# How to get Domain Credential programmatically in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, single-sign-on, credentials, autodiscovery

I am trying to get a Mac application that get the domain  credential from the Mac behind the Active Directory. The user logs into the Mac as a Domain user.

We don't want to prompt the user again since they already provided the username/ password when they logged into the computer.